# C program to output array lists and then swap the elements between lists and output them again

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having difficulty printing my second list when inputted by the user. Only the first list prints. Also, I'm not sure how to proceed in swapping the list values and then printing them. My instructor wants us to figure out how to do this without writing a function but I can't see a way without involving that. Here is my code so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int List1[5], List2[5];
int i, j;

printf("Please enter the values to List1 array\n ");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", &List1[i]);
}

printf("Please enter the values to List2 array\n");
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++);
{
    scanf_s("%d", &List2[j]);
}

printf("List1 and List2 before swap\n");

printf("\nList1\t\t List 2\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", List1[i]);
}

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++);
{
    printf("%d\n", List2[j]);
}


 //??? put something here to swap the elements and 

printf("\nList1 and List2 after swap");



return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < 5; j++);` -- what does each character in this line do? (are there any that don't belong that could cause problems?) What is different between this loop declaration and the one before it?

Comment: As David C. Rankin already said: Compare your `i` for-loop with the `j` for-loop character-by-character and you'll notice one extra character that shall be removed. For swapping just make one more loop: `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){int tmp = List1[i]; List1[i] = List2[i]; List2[i] = tmp;}`

Answer (score 0):

These are not a linked lists, they're just int vectors, if you want to swap two linked list, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Structure
{
  int n;
};

struct StructureNode
{
  struct Structure structure;
  struct StructureNode * next;
};

typedef struct StructureNode * Node;

void NewNode(struct Structure s, Node * p )
{
  Node temp;

  temp = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct StructureNode));

  temp->structure = s;

  temp->next = *p;

  *p = temp;
}

void Read(struct Structure * p)
{
  printf("Insert a number in the list:");
  scanf("%d", &p->n);
}

void ViewLists(Node head1, Node head2)
{
  printf("List1:\n");
  while(head1 != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n", head1->structure.n);
    head1 = head1->next;
  }
  printf("List2:\n");
  while(head2 != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n", head2->structure.n);
    head2 = head2->next;
  }
}

void SwapLists(Node  head1, Node  head2)
{
  struct Structure temp;
  while(head1 != NULL && head2 != NULL)
  {
    temp = head1->structure;
    head1->structure = head2->structure;
    head2->structure = temp;

    head1 = head1->next;
    head2 = head2->next;
  }
}

int Menu()
{
  int c;
  printf("\nHow to swap two linked list by St3veR0nix\n"
        "\n1) Insert a value in List1\n"
        "\n2) Insert a value in List2\n"
        "\n3) Swap the lists\n"
        "\n4) Print both lists\n"
        "\n>>");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  return c;
}

int main()
{
  Node head1 = NULL;
  Node head2 = NULL;
  struct Structure s;
  int c;
  do {
    c = Menu();
    switch(c)
    {
      case 1: Read(&s);
              NewNode(s, &head1);
              break;
      case 2: Read(&s);
              NewNode(s, &head2);
              break;
      case 3: SwapLists(head1, head2);
              break;
      case 4: ViewLists(head1, head2);
              break;
      default: c = 0;
    }
  } while(c != 0);

}
```

Comment: SO never wanted to implement as a linked list. It was a plain array that he was interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Just one glaring error in your code @RTR81. The `for` loops you have used for the `List2` array, i.e, the `j` loop has a semi colon at the end of the `for` statement. This causes the loop to end even before it moves to the second iteration. Just removing the semicolon(;) at the end would make it possible for you to read the entire input array.

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++);   //this semicolon needs to be removed.
```

And now coming to the swapping part. It is pretty simple buddy. Declare another variable, say `temp`, which hold the value of `List1` element at first, while you put the value of `List2` element in it. Then put the value of `temp` into the `List2` element.

I have posted the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int List1[5], List2[5];
int i, j, temp;

printf("Please enter the values to List1 array\n ");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &List1[i]);
}

printf("Please enter the values to List2 array\n");
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)//removed the semicolon here
{
    scanf("%d", &List2[j]);
}

printf("List1 and List2 before swap\n");

printf("\nList 1:");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("\t%d", List1[i]);
}

printf("\nList 2:");

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)//removed the semicolon here
{
    printf("\t%d", List2[j]);
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    temp = List1[i];
    List1[i] = List2[i];
    List2[i] = temp;
}

 //??? put something here to swap the elements and 

printf("\nList1 and List2 after swap");
printf("\nList 1:");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("\t%d", List1[i]);
}

printf("\nList 2:");

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)//removed the semicolon here
{
    printf("\t%d", List2[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

This results in the output as follows:

> ```
> > Please enter the values to List1 array   
>
> >1 2 3 4 5 
>
> >Please enter the values to List2 array
>
> >9 8 7 6 5 
> >
> >List1 and List2 before swap
> > 
> > List 1: 1   2   3   4   5 
>
> >List 2:  9   8   7   6   5 
>
> >List1 and List2 after swap 
>
> >List 1:  9   8   7   6   5 
>
> >List 2:  1   2   3   4   5
> ```

Hope this helped!